# PDO Dynamically Add Column to Multiple Tables with Wildcard Name

Tags: php, pdo

I have a code below where it adds a column named `"age"` to a table named `"us@house"`.

```
$table = 'us@house';
$column = 'age';

$sql = $DB_CON_C->query("ALTER TABLE `".$table."` ADD $column VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER id");
$sql->execute();
```

This code works well for me. However, within my database I have multiple tables (about 20 of them and the table name for each has "@" as you can see in my code) where I need to add the same column "age" to each of them. Does anyone know how to change the existing code to achieve this with wildcard? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve this with wildcards. What you could do is to write a stored procedure that enumerates all the tables that match your format and performs the necessary changes. Alternatively, you could run multiple queries through PHP as follows:

```
$tab_prefixes = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$tab_suffix = '@house';

foreach ($tab_prefixes as $tab_prefix)
{
    $sql = $DB_CON_C->query("ALTER TABLE `".$tab_prefix.$tab_suffix."` ADD age VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER id");
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tommaaso. I appreciate your help and explanation.